# how do I add a comma or split my data in a cell into different columns?

Tags: excel

For example i have this data:

```
theneedledropReach780.4KCountrySaudi ArabiaCategoryTechAudienceMale 18-24 (39%)Audience CountryUSARatingNot Rated Invite  Profile

Watt SopaReach1.36MCountryMexicoCategoryOtherAudienceUnknownAudience CountryUnknownRatingNot Rated Invite  Profile

CreativenailartReach9.70MCountryNetherlandsCategoryBeauty & FashionAudienceFemale 25-34 (25%)Audience CountryUSARatingNot Rated Invite  Profile
```

And I want to create new columns after the word reach,countr, category, audience, and rating. right now all that information is in one cell.

I have about 1000cells that need to be split into coloumns so its hard to do it manually

How would I do this?

Comment: Oooh that's some fun looking unparsed data - How do you know where in each string to split it? Do you have a complete list of the delimiters? And will they always show up in the same order?

Comment: Low hanging fruit I would suggest copy and paste into word. Find and replace each of your words in your document with the same word and a tab character ie Find "reach" Replace with "reach^t". Copy and paste as text back into excel. Seperated into columns.

Comment: Yes every row is layed out in the same way, and im completely new to this so im not sure what delimiters are. And I want to split when I see the words Reach, than another when the word Country, then category, then audience, then rating.

Comment: @nbayly what would the reach^t do?

Comment: "reach" was one of the delimiters from your post. The "^t" is the special character in Word Find and replace for a tab. So if you had "heneedledropReach780" and ran the replace you would have "heneedledropReach [TAB] 780". [TAB] representing and actual tab character. When then you copy back into excel it will interpret a tab as the start of a new column.

Comment: Is there a possibility of your delimiters existing in the string, where you *don't* want to use that as a delimiter? For example, could you possibly have `texttextcountry flavorcountrytexttext`, where you'd want to keep "flavor country" and not just "flavor"?

Comment: Just going through your history.  There is a check mark by the answers.  This is where the one who posed the question can mark the answer as the correct answer.  It is something only one who posed the question can do.  If you never mark any answer as correct there are those that will stop helping.  Please go back through your history and mark those answers that helped you as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula in B1:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,CHOOSE(COLUMN(A:A),"","Reach","Country","Category","Audience","Rating"),REPT(" ",999)),CHOOSE(COLUMN(A:A),"Reach","Country","Category","Audience","Rating","Profile"),REPT(" ",999)),IF(COLUMN(A:A) = 1,1,999),999))
```

Then copy/drag over to G1 and copy/drag that down the length of the data.

[image]